# How can i make my parameter expand in preview mode in ssrs report?

Tags: reporting-services, report

I want to see my parameter expanded when i run my report in Preview mode.

[image]

I expected this :

[image]

but without clicking on the arrow? Something like textarea when i preview my report.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible using the parameters section.

The only way you could show all the parameters at once and be able to select them would be to include a table in the report itself that lists the possible options and when clicked on, reloads the report taking that selection in to account.

That or use a custom report viewer.